# Integral on a surface

Tags: integration

Let $D$ be the parallelogram on the $(x,y)$ plane ($z=0$) that comes from the intersection of the lines: $y=x$, $x = \pi$, $y = x + \pi$ and $x=0$.

Compute the following integral:

$$ \int_S \sqrt{ 1 + 2 \cos^2(y-x) } dS $$

where $S$ is the surface described by the equation $z = \sin(y-x)$ projected on $D$.

Comment: I guess you mean to say that the integration is performed over the surface
$$
   S = \{ (x,y,z): z = \sin(y-x), \text{ and } (x,y) \in D \}
$$

Comment: I hope so.. I found the question in a book so I reported it as it is formulated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's parametrize your surface using $(u,v) \in (0,1) \times (0,1)$ as follows:
$$
   x(u,v) = \pi u, \quad y(u,v) = \pi (u+v), \quad z(u,v) = \sin( \pi v)
$$
The induced measure $\mathrm{d}S$ is defined as follows
$$
   \mathrm{d}S = n_x \mathrm{d}y \wedge \mathrm{d}z + n_y \mathrm{d} z \wedge \mathrm{d} x +n_z \mathrm{d} x \wedge \mathrm{d} y
$$
where $n_x = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(z-\sin(y-x)\right) = \cos(y-x) = \cos(\pi v)$, $n_y = -\cos(y-x) = -\cos(\pi v)$, $n_z = 1$. Furthermore:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
  \mathrm{d} y \wedge \mathrm{d} z &=& \pi^2 \cos(\pi v) \mathrm{d} u \wedge \mathrm{d} v \\
  \mathrm{d} z \wedge \mathrm{d} x &=& = - \pi^2 \cos(\pi v) \mathrm{d} u \wedge \mathrm{d} v \\
  \mathrm{d} x \wedge \mathrm{d} y &=& \pi^2 \mathrm{d} u \wedge \mathrm{d} v
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Combining, we arrive at the expression for induced measure:
$$
   \mathrm{d} S = \pi^2 \left(1 + 2 \cos^2(\pi v) \right)\mathrm{d} u \wedge \mathrm{d} v
$$
Using this measure, the integral becomes:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \int \int \sqrt{1 + 2 \cos^2(y-x) } \mathrm{d} S &=& \pi^2 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 
\left(1 + 2 \cos^2(\pi v)\right)^{3/2} \mathrm{d} u \mathrm{d} v \\ &=& \pi^2 \int_0^1 
\left(1 + 2 \cos^2(\pi v)\right)^{3/2}  \mathrm{d} v \\
   &\stackrel{t=\cos(\pi v)}{=}& \pi \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\left(1+2 t^2\right)^{3/2}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} \mathrm{d} t \\
  &=& \frac{2\pi}{3} \left( 8 \mathsf{E}\left(-2\right) - 3 \mathsf{K}\left(-2\right)\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where $\mathsf{K}(m) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{ \mathrm{d} \phi}{\sqrt{1- m \sin^2(\phi)}}$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind), and $\mathsf{E}(m) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1- m \sin^2(\phi)}\mathrm{d} \phi$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I 'm pretty sure there exists an "easier" one. Any other ways?